# I need this to write to a file named derp.txt but it creates or replaces the file, then writes to it

Tags: java

Here is the code for the writing to file part:

```
    BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("derp.txt"));
    write.write("Tries: "+tries+" - Max: "+max);
    write.newLine();
    write.flush();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new FileWriter("derp.txt", true)` 
will create a `FileWriter` for appending to an existing file.